# Pass Dynamic values to the rules in ANTLR4 grammar

Tags: antlr4

I am newbie to ANTLR4
I want to write a grammar that would parse the syntax using the values which it reads dynamically.
Say  my grammar is as follows in image

[image]

I need help such the HANDLERID not only takes the values mentioned,but a list of values based on a function call,dynamic values. For example a function return list containing `{'ACD','GHY','XYZ' ..}`. Not to confuse with identifier,these values are names of some defined set of objects, so writing a grammar for IDENTIFIER is not solution.

Any help is appeciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [actions](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/actions.md) are a viable solution? These are written in the target language and allow to do all kind of processing. Formulated as a predicate (appending a `?` to the action block) they can even be used to guide the parser what path to take.

Here's a typical form:

```
decl: type ID ';' { System.out.println("found a decl"); };
```

or as a predicate:

```
HANDLERID: ID { isSpecialWord($ID.text) }?;
```

which will only be matched for IDs that your internal function `isSpecialWord` is returning true for. So essentially, you are not passing the lexer rule some values, but you do the evaluation in internal code.